# Access prior element in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've looked around into list comprehensions on here, and can find a solution for this.

Closest I've come is questions that advice using [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) while iterating in a list comprehension.

What I'd like to do is access the prior element in a list comprehension. [The context is this question on another StackExchange site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18960/expand-tabs-implement-expand1).

Basically, if I get this string from `stdin` - `4,6,+2,+8`, I'd like to output the array that is the integer of the number, or the number plus the value of the prior element. In the given case the final array is: `4,6,8,16` - or `4,6,6+2,(6+2)+8`. Going from left to right with an array and for loop its trivial to generate, but I'm curious to know if it can be done in a single list comprehension.

As for what I have:

```
from sys import*
s=argv[1].split(',')
for i in range(len(s)):
 s[i]=eval(`s[i-1]`*(s[i][0]=='+')+s[i])
print s
```

Which prints the correct result, however the following list comprehension does not:

```
s=argv[1].split(',')
s=[eval(s[i-1]*(x[0]=='+')+x) for i,x in enumerate(s)]
print s
```

Which results in:

```
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Which is equivilient to `4, 6, +2+6, +2+8`.

What I'd like to be able to do finally is something along the lines of:

```
s=[eval(PRIOR_VALUE*(x[0]=='+')+x) for x in argv[1].split(',')]
```

So can I easily access the prior computed element of a list comprehension in the same list comprehension?

Comment: This might be complicated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So can I easily access the prior computed element of a list comprehension in the same list comprehension?

Easily? No.

If you want to make things difficult for yourself, there are plenty of ways to save state information in a list comprehension. For example,

```
prev = [None]

s = [prev.__setitem__(0, val) or val
     for item in list
     for val in [something(item, prev[0])]]
```

This is not a good idea.

Comment: I might try a different approach. Cheers.